# In C++ using NaCl how to sort a JSON object by value?

Tags: c++, arrays, json, sorting, google-nativeclient

I'm using [PicoJSON](https://github.com/kazuho/picojson) to handle JSON that I get from JavaScript into C++.

If I have a JSON with keys and values of the form `{"val1":3, "val2":4}` I can get the value of every specific key like so:

```
picojson::value v;

const string json2("{\"val1\":3,\"val2\":4}");

int val1 = (int)v.get("val1").get<double>(); // val1 will be equal to 3
int val2 = (int)v.get("val2").get<double>(); // val2 will be equal to 4
```

The problem is that I have an **array of objects** coming from **JavaScript** in the form of JSON that look like `[{"name": 3},{"name": 1},{"name": 2}]`. So now the code will look like this:

```
picojson::value v;
const string json1("[{\"name\": 3},{\"name\": 1},{\"name\": 2}]");
```

**I am expected to sort them** so the **expected output should be:**

```
"[{\"name\": 1},{\"name\": 2},{\"name\": 3}]"
```

- Do I have to use a *'for loop'* with a *linked list* to somehow extract that data to sort it? If so, how?
- Maybe this can be extracted using *regular expressions*? If so, how?
- Should the array can be converted into *array of arrays* in order to sort it? If so, how?
- Do I have to *build a struct or a vector* to get a sortable data structure recognisable by
  C++? If so, how?

***Note:** The number of elements varies - it can be greater/smaller.*

## **EDIT:**

Can this task be solved if the data structure is in this form (just like I had with `{"val1":3, "val2":4}` ) :

```
{"name3": 3, "name1" : 1, "name2": 2, "name97" : 97, ... }
```

I am flexible to changing it so that C++ would be able to handle it.

Would it then be possible to traverse every **key** and sort in by **value** ? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: just to clarify: so the variable names are all the same, just the value differs, and you want to sort by the value?

Comment: yes, for simplicity reasons variable names are the same

Comment: hm don't know picojson but at a quick look at it I couldn't see any way to get an iterator or a collection out of it - meaning you won't be able to run a std::sort directly on it somehow, you'd first have to extract the values yourself anyway...

Comment: if there is an alternative library for C++ that can handle JSON, I'm open to that - as long as it is possible to sort it. If not, I'll be changing the data structure on the JavaScript end to look like: {"name3": 3, "name1" : 1, "name2": 2}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your data into a vector and sort it.

```
array arr = v.get<array>();
vector<int> vi;
for (array::const_iterator it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end(); ++it) {
  vi.push_back((int)(*it).get("name").get<double>());
}
sort(vi.begin(), vi.end());

stringstream ss;
vector<int>::const_iterator it;
for (ss<<"[", it = vi.begin(); (it+1) != vi.end(); ++it) {
  ss<<"{\"name\": "<<(*it)<<"},";
}
ss<<"{\"name\": "<<(*it)<<"}]";

cout<<"Output: "<<ss.str()<<endl;
```

Here is outputs:

```
Input:  [{"name": 3},{"name": 1},{"name": 2}]
Output: [{"name": 1},{"name": 2},{"name": 3}]
```